# Google Sheets - Sum unique rows in

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I am trying to sum all values of a unique pair of rows and sort, for example:

Input:
 Name -|-   Last -|-    Expenses 
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Bruce   Wayne   100
Jack    Napier  75
Bruce   Wayne   50
Jack    Napier  5
Selina  Kyle    90

Output:
 Name   -|- Last    -|- Expenses 
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Bruce   Wayne   150
Selina  Kyle    90
Jack    Napier  80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
=query(A1:C6,"select A, B, sum(C) group by B, A 
              order by sum(C) desc, B, A 
              label sum(C) 'Expenses' ",1)
```

Here is a sample table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WeQZ3U8ZGziQiDZUoJbvF4cwFif16oePTq8jlICvL88/edit?usp=sharing

This sorts the records descending by amount, plus alphabetically by Last then First name.

Let us know if this doesn't answer your question.
Good luck.